# Rotating elements i to j in an array

Tags: ruby

Given an array:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I want to rotate elements `i` through `j` in some direction `n` times. So, for example:

```
i = 2
j = 3
n = 1
```

Rotating `a` will produce:

```
new_a = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6]
```

This is what I have:

```
def rotate_sub(a, i, j, n)
  return a[0...i] + a[i..j].rotate(n) + a[j+1..-1]
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? Since there is no bound-checks, `i` or `j` could very well be outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Hmm, add bound checks and you're good to go, aren't you? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a magical way, so perhaps the simplest is the best:

```
def rotate_sub(a, i, j, n)
  a[0...i] + a[i..j].rotate(n) + a[j+1..-1] if i < j && j < a.size
end
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to mutate the original array you could do something like:

```
a[i..j] = a[i..j].rotate n
```

But I like the functional solution you already have.

Comment: If you use `dup`, you can use your way even when not changing the original.